# Como faço para ler e separar os guardar os dados separados pelos ponto e virgula e virgula?

Tags: c

Boa noite pessoal, estou fazendo um programa em c que tem de ler um ficheiro e guardar os dados, sendo que cada linha do ficheiro representam os dados de um cliente, como faço para ele guardar os dados separando ele por esses ";" e ","?
O ficheiro a ser lido é:

ficheiro.txt
1 ; Familiar ; 2 ; 2 ; I 3 , M 3 , BR 4 , AL 2
2 ; Individual ; 1 ; I 2 , M 2
3 ; Familiar ; 1 ; 0 ; AB 2 , AM 3 , AL 5 , BR 2
4 ; Individual ; 0 ; AL 3 , BR 2

Answer (score 0):

Veja um exemplo aqui:

```
Dados ficheiro:  
emilio silva ; 25 , 2 , 2017
carla patricia , 3 , 4 , 2016
Silvia Pereira ; 25 , 8 , 2015
Miguel Antonio, 7 , 8 , 2014
```

Codigo:

```
int main(void){

    FILE *fp = fopen("testo.txt", "r");

    char linha[100];
    int dia, mes, ano;
    char nome[50], apelido[50];

    if(fp != NULL) {

        while(fgets(linha, 100, fp)){

            sscanf(linha, "%s %s ; %d , %d , %d", nome, apelido, &dia, &mes, &ano);

            printf("\n%s %s, %d %d %d\n", nome, apelido, dia, mes, ano);
        }
    } else {
        printf("\nErro");
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```